# Unable to read cookie header with Angular

Tags: angularjs, cookies, sails.js

I'm stacking on a shit problem and can't find a solution... maybe has someone an idea.

I have a rest api based on sails.js and send a post request via Angular.js - works fine I get all response data!

But im unable to read the header cookie. The cookie is always null...

In the header should be a 'Set-Cookie'. If I call the same function with a Rest tool I get the cookie header.

I'm working local host port :8000. The rest api is on port :1337

```
$http.post(url, json)
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

            console.log(headers('Server'));
            console.log(headers('Set-Cookie'));
        })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          console.log("error");
          console.log("status " +status);
          console.log("status " +angular.toJson(data));
        });
```

Any idea?

Cheers!!

Comment: Try to dump `headers()`. Maybe there is no `Set-Cookie` property,and header has some kind of normalized name,e.g. `SetCookie` .

Comment: No I don't see anything if I call console.log(headers());

Comment: REST tools have different access, check to see if your CORS (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) properties match, MAYBE that's why you can't read the header properties.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should never need to get the `set-cookie` header in Javascript; the browser handles setting the cookie for you.  If you want to check if the cookie was part of the response, it's better to use your browser's development console.

More to the point, the issue here is that the cookie is not going to be set at all since this is a cross-origin AJAX request (different ports counts as a different origin) and you probably haven't set the CORS settings in Sails to allow the request through.

The full documentation for CORS in Sails is [here](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-docs/blob/0.9/config.cors.md).  The easiest way to get started with testing it is to open your `/config/cors.js` file and set `allRoutes` to `true`; this will allow all CORS requests to go through unimpeded, regardless of their origin or the route they're trying to access.  Once you've got that working, you can use the more fine-grained settings to lock down access if you want.

Note that by default, only a [very few](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#simple-response-header) response headers from a cross-origin request will be made available via Javascript, of which `set-cookie` is definitely not one!